# How to drop "unique_together" constraint

Tags: django-models

I used the unique_together between to fields and after some time and new requirements I've decided I want to remove it so I deleted it from the models definition, but still it seems to be causing "Duplicate entry" problems.
Do I have to drop some constraint on the database? in that case, how can I do it (I use phpmyadmin).

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be a compound `UNIQUE` index on the table. Drop that.

Comment: Thanks! You gave a good clue :)
I did 
SHOW INDEX FROM mytable;
to see what the name of index was and then I just dropped it
DROP INDEX index_name ON mytable

Comment: so SCHEMAMIGRATE on south will not do this?

Comment: @dashesy I don't know if now it does, but at that time deleting the definition did not produce any change for south. ("Nothing seems to have changed")